# Why are convolutions preferred to local receptive fields?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, computer-vision

It is my intuition that unrestricted / unshared weights encourage the network to capture more invariances than in the case of convolutions, where the weights are shared. (These capture mostly translational invariances). See [this](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4136-tiled-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) and [this](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/unsupervised_icml2012.pdf).

If sharing weights actually results in less invariant feature detectors, why are convolutional layers preferred? Is it just because they're faster?

Answer (score 1):

Convolutions are preferred because they capture global translational invariances.

A layer with Local receptive fields (LRF) which does not share weights across the entire input structure does not capture them.

In the second [link](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/unsupervised_icml2012.pdf) that you cite, the proposed model does not need such invariance because it is applied to a face recognition problem for which the images are centered.

In particular, each LRF is associated to the same kind of region for each image. A LRF in the hair would capture information very different from a LRF in the eye for example, thus it makes little sense to make them share weights.

Certainly this implementation is clever for this type of dataset but is at a greater computational cost.

In the first [link](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4136-tiled-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf), there is actually weight sharing. The parameter $k$ controls the number of steps away the weights of a LRF are shared with another LRF, allowing them to capture the wanted translational invariances as well as other additional invariances.

They showed that their model works best for $k=2$. In this case, the number of parameters is only doubled (a LRF has its weights shared with half of all LRF).

A good explanation about parameter sharing can be found on wikipedia's cnn [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network#Parameter_Sharing).